# Why does pandas sometimes use the argument 'dropna' and sometimes 'skipna' in its methods?

Tags: pandas

Please consider this either a question or a suggestion. Pandas sometimes uses the argument 'dropna' in its methods and sometimes 'skipna' as in the following two cases:

```
history_trans['category_2'].value_counts(dropna = False)
history_trans['category_2'].median(skipna = False)
```

It may be better to use 'skipna' in both the cases unless there are some special reasons for using two different names for the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the doc

> ```
> median :skipna : boolean, default True
>
> Exclude NA/null values when computing the result.
> ```

---

> ```
> value_counts: dropna : boolean, default True
>
> Don’t include counts of NaN.
> ```

So the `value_count` will dropna at the end when print the output(default) , but the median will return the value by not consider `nan` during the calculation, so basically these two are aim two different target.